# Escaping period in Ack.vim

Tags: vim, ack

I'm looking forward to search for the following pattern with **Ack.vim**:

`.section`

Where `.` should only match a period, and not any character.

I tried the following:

- `\.section`
- `[.]section`
- `-Q .section`

What is the correct way of escaping the period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

For instance, '#'. 
      You have to escape it like this `:Ack '\\\#define foo'` to search for `'#define foo'`.

Use: `:Ack \\\.section`

Comment: If I use Vim's build in search facility, the above works, however the question is about searching with Ack.vim.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

For instance, '#'. 
      You have to escape it like this `:Ack '\\\#define foo'` to search for `'#define foo'`.

Comment: It works when using Vim's built-in search functionality, however the approaches mentioned above doesn't work with Ack for some reason.